# Preserving row labels where no data exists SSRS Tablix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have a dataset that shows capacity groupings for grads of different years. Groupings as follows:

0-100000 
100000-250000 
250000-500000 
500000-1000000 
1000000+

However for some of the years there are no grads which fulfil any of the capacity groupings. How do I still retain these labels, even if there is no data?

[image]

Need 
[image]

I've seen similar issues posted, but nothing that quite captures exactly what I am trying to accomplish. So far I've tried to add blank rows in the backend SQL by unioning in a temp table to fill all the blank values, but it seems a bit cumbersome/inefficient... Is there some kind of trick within SSRS or does it really just come down to data manipulation with SQL? 
-Thanks

Comment: SSRS can't show you what is not there. So SQL is your only option for this.

So what you could do is create a temp table which has all your group ranges and then join your data back to this table to pad out your data.

Comment: Or you could use a MATRIX and have the years as a column to show all the row labels for all years.